# How to query an "array of objects" (multiple filters) with Google Datastore

Tags: node.js, database, google-cloud-datastore

I think I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out.
I use `Google Datastore` (via `nodeJS`) and I'd like to write a simple query.

Let's consider a DB with these 2 simplified entities where `collaborator` 
 stands for "`someone` has an access to this entity until `some date`":

```
ENTITY #1
{ ID: 'entity1',
  FEATURE_A: false,
  COLLABORATORS: 
   [ 
    { UNTIL: '2018-06-04T19:00:00.369Z', EMAIL: 'A@A.com'},
    { UNTIL: '2018-06-04T20:00:00.369Z', EMAIL: 'B@B.com'}
   ]
 }

ENTITY #2
{ ID: 'entity2',
  FEATURE_A: true,
  COLLABORATORS: 
   [ 
    { UNTIL: '2018-06-10T13:00:00.369Z', EMAIL: 'A@A.com'},
    { UNTIL: '2018-08-05T10:00:00.369Z', EMAIL: 'B@B.com'}
   ]
 }
```

How do I write a query that get all entities `WHERE` collaborator contains `A@A.com` and **for which** `A@A.com` has still an access because `today()` < `UNTIL`?

Query with multiple filters doesn't seem to work with an array of objects...
Do I "just" need to write a composite index? I don't know how to do it at this time, but is it the road to walk?

Thanks.

---

This is the "array" as written into my Datastore console

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "entityValue": {
        "properties": {
          "ACCESS": {
            "stringValue": "full"
          },
          "EMAIL": {
            "stringValue": "A@A.com"
          },
          "CREATEDAT": {
            "timestampValue": "2018-06-03T19:23:17.728Z"
          },
          "CREATOR": {
            "booleanValue": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "entityValue": {
        "properties": {
          "UNTIL": {
            "stringValue": "2018-06-13T19:24:52.131Z"
          },
          "ACCESS": {
            "stringValue": "full"
          },
          "EMAIL": {
            "stringValue": "B@B.com"
          },
          "CREATEDAT": {
            "timestampValue": "2018-06-03T19:24:52.135Z"
          },
          "CREATOR": {
            "booleanValue": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how did you create this entity?, I have tried to create a similar structure but I've had no success. 

Your structure is a 3-dimensional array, right?

Comment: No, these are really super simple entities with just one property made of an "array of objects" (I cleaned up the 2 DB entities).

Answer (score 1):

Writing this as an answer because I don't seem to find the way to properly insert code in the comments.

The most similar structure I could reproduce to copy the COLLABORATORS block was the following array structure::

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "entityValue": {
        "properties": {
          "UNTIL": {
            "stringValue": "1st"
          },
          "EMAIL": {
            "stringValue": "A@A.com"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "entityValue": {
        "properties": {
          "UNTIL": {
            "stringValue": "2nd"
          },
          "EMAIL": {
            "stringValue": "B@B.com"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Even like that I cannot get to obtain an exact copy of your entity because then the field of COLLABORATORS is shown like this:

```
[{"UNTIL":"1st","EMAIL":"A@A.com"},   
{"UNTIL":"2nd","EMAIL":"B@B.com"}]
```

Which is not strictly the same because "UNTIL" and "EMAIL" are quoted. Can you post the code of your structure?

Comment: I've updated my question to copy my entity subarray. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nerotulip I think you were in the right track. So far I've been able to see investigate, I think it is not possible to execute this query without a composite Index.

Aparently only the equality filter will accept non-composite indexes with multiple fields.

Comment: Do you have any clue how to write such an index. I was reading GCP documentation and I still haven't figure it out... Thx.